# the binary being analyzed must be an executable

Tags: ios

I am trying to upload an app for Apple to review, but not sure what I am doing wrong to receive this error message - 'the binary must be an executable'. The zip file name looks as it should with no white space visible in the project name, except for the name at the end of the path. Example - ProjectName.app.zip/ProjectName.app/Project Name. This ending still has a white space in between and I am not sure where it is located. Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the "executable" permission to the actual executable file before zipping it up.  Using the command line, it would be something like:

chmod 755 .../ProjectName.app/ProjectName

It's odd because you don't need to do that step for ad-hoc development builds, but Application Loader requires it and will fail with the error you mentioned if you don't.